# How to use sqlite to retrieve single result?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have this code that retrieves the last id

```
 public int retrieveLastId() {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select "+ RECORDING_ID +" from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY "+ RECORDING_ID +" DESC LIMIT 1 ", null);


            int last = 0;
            last = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            Log.e("sfsdlkfjs dfl sd",cursor.getString(0));
            return  last;
        }
```

but I get an error android.database.cursorindexoutofboundsexception
how do I return the last id properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cause of error is you do not check cursor is null .

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) // Check your cursor has value?
   System.out.println(cursor.getString(0); 

cursor.close();    //you should realse cursor
```

Comment: thanks! heres what I did 
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  last = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have values in the table. If it doesn't have it will end up with exception with your code.

Try doing this changes in your code.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){cursor.moveToFirst()
    do{
        bankbalresult = cursor.getString(0);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());}
```